# Python chess engine. Alphabeta function exceeding depth call error

Tags: python, chess

I've recently been working on a project where the goal is to make a chess engine that can evaluate a certain position and play the best moves. I used [this post](https://medium.com/dscvitpune/lets-create-a-chess-ai-8542a12afef) as a base for this project but came to realize that it wasn't what I was looking for.
Source code : [github](https://github.com/AnshGaikwad/Chess-World)

My code:

```
def do_move(depth):

try:
    move = chess.polyglot.MemoryMappedReader("C:/Users/Bruno/Desktop/pws/books/human.bin").weighted_choice(board).move
    move = chess.polyglot.MemoryMappedReader("C:/Users/Bruno/Desktop/pws/books/computer.bin").weighted_choice(board).move
    move = chess.polyglot.MemoryMappedReader("C:/Users/Bruno/Desktop/pws/books/pecg_book.bin").weighted_choice(board).move
    return move
except:
    bestMove = chess.Move.null()
    bestValue = -99999
    alpha = -100000
    beta = 100000
    for move in board.legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        boardValue = -alphabeta(-beta, -alpha, (depth -1))
        if boardValue > bestValue:
            bestValue = boardValue
            bestMove = move
        if (boardValue > alpha):
            alpha = boardValue
            board.pop()
    return bestMove

def alphabeta(depthleft, alpha, beta):
    bestscore = -9999
    if (depthleft == 0):
        return quiesce(alpha, beta)
    for move in board.legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        score = -alphabeta(-beta, -alpha, depthleft - 1)
        board.pop()
        if (score >= beta):
            return score
        if (score > bestscore):
        bestscore = score
        if (score > alpha):
        alpha = score
    return bestscore

def quiesce(alpha, beta):
    stand_pat = evaluation()
    if (stand_pat >= beta):
        return beta
    if (alpha < stand_pat):
        alpha = stand_pat
    for move in board.legal_moves:
        if board.is_capture(move):
            board.push(move)
            score = -quiesce(-beta, -alpha)
            board.pop()
        if (score >= beta):
            return beta
        if (score > alpha):
            alpha = score
            return alpha
```

Currently, the code can perform around 20 or so moves before crashing due to excessive calls of the do_move() function.

How can I fix this and make it play a full game?

Comment: Rewrite your code as an iterative solution instead of using recursion.

Comment: Presumably you've done enough Python to realise that indentation matters and that you're code does not make sense? Code examples like this should be a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the indentation error, but it was just a formatting issue after copying the code. It should be fixed now, although that didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code based from your github link with modifications. User can input position and let the engine search for bestmove. Note time is in milliseconds. See sample output. It uses the [python chess library](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

#### Code

```
import time

import chess
import chess.pgn


INF = 100000
MATE_SCORE = INF-100
MAX_DEPTH = 16
MAX_TIME_MS = 120000  # 120s or 2m


# Evaluating the board
pawntable = [
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    5, 10, 10, -20, -20, 10, 10, 5,
    5, -5, -10, 0, 0, -10, -5, 5,
    0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0,
    5, 5, 10, 25, 25, 10, 5, 5,
    10, 10, 20, 30, 30, 20, 10, 10,
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

knightstable = [
    -50, -40, -30, -30, -30, -30, -40, -50,
    -40, -20, 0, 5, 5, 0, -20, -40,
    -30, 5, 10, 15, 15, 10, 5, -30,
    -30, 0, 15, 20, 20, 15, 0, -30,
    -30, 5, 15, 20, 20, 15, 5, -30,
    -30, 0, 10, 15, 15, 10, 0, -30,
    -40, -20, 0, 0, 0, 0, -20, -40,
    -50, -40, -30, -30, -30, -30, -40, -50]

bishopstable = [
    -20, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -20,
    -10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, -10,
    -10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, -10,
    -10, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, -10,
    -10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, -10,
    -10, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, -10,
    -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10,
    -20, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -20]

rookstable = [
    0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0,
    -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5,
    -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5,
    -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5,
    -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5,
    -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5,
    5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

queenstable = [
    -20, -10, -10, -5, -5, -10, -10, -20,
    -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10,
    -10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, -10,
    0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, -5,
    -5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, -5,
    -10, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, -10,
    -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10,
    -20, -10, -10, -5, -5, -10, -10, -20]

kingstable = [
    20, 30, 10, 0, 0, 10, 30, 20,
    20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20,
    -10, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -10,
    -20, -30, -30, -40, -40, -30, -30, -20,
    -30, -40, -40, -50, -50, -40, -40, -30,
    -30, -40, -40, -50, -50, -40, -40, -30,
    -30, -40, -40, -50, -50, -40, -40, -30,
    -30, -40, -40, -50, -50, -40, -40, -30]


def is_time_limit_reached():
    global start_time
    global timems

    return 1000 * (time.perf_counter() - start_time) >= timems


def evaluate_board(board):
    wp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.WHITE))
    bp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.BLACK))
    wn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.WHITE))
    bn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.BLACK))
    wb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.WHITE))
    bb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.BLACK))
    wr = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.WHITE))
    br = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.BLACK))
    wq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.WHITE))
    bq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.BLACK))

    material = 100 * (wp - bp) + 320 * (wn - bn) + 330 * (wb - bb) + 500 * (wr - br) + 900 * (wq - bq)

    pawnsq = sum([pawntable[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.WHITE)])
    pawnsq = pawnsq + sum([-pawntable[chess.square_mirror(i)]
                           for i in board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.BLACK)])
    knightsq = sum([knightstable[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.WHITE)])
    knightsq = knightsq + sum([-knightstable[chess.square_mirror(i)]
                               for i in board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.BLACK)])
    bishopsq = sum([bishopstable[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.WHITE)])
    bishopsq = bishopsq + sum([-bishopstable[chess.square_mirror(i)]
                               for i in board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.BLACK)])
    rooksq = sum([rookstable[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.WHITE)])
    rooksq = rooksq + sum([-rookstable[chess.square_mirror(i)]
                           for i in board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.BLACK)])
    queensq = sum([queenstable[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.WHITE)])
    queensq = queensq + sum([-queenstable[chess.square_mirror(i)]
                             for i in board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.BLACK)])
    kingsq = sum([kingstable[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.KING, chess.WHITE)])
    kingsq = kingsq + sum([-kingstable[chess.square_mirror(i)]
                           for i in board.pieces(chess.KING, chess.BLACK)])

    eval = material + pawnsq + knightsq + bishopsq + rooksq + queensq + kingsq

    if board.turn:
        return eval
    return -eval


def value_to_mate(value):
    if (value < -MATE_SCORE):
        return -(INF + value) // 2
    
    elif (value > MATE_SCORE):
        return (INF - value + 1) // 2

    return 0


# Searching the best move using minimax and alphabeta algorithm with negamax implementation
def alphabeta(board, alpha, beta, depth):
    global timems
    global start_time
    global ply

    bestscore = -INF

    if is_time_limit_reached():
        return 0

    if board.can_claim_draw() or board.is_insufficient_material():
        return 0

    incheck = board.is_check()
    if incheck:
        depth += 1

    if (depth < 1):
        return quiesce(board, alpha, beta)

    legal = 0
    for move in board.legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        ply += 1
        legal += 1

        score = -alphabeta(board, -beta, -alpha, depth - 1)
        board.pop()
        ply -= 1

        if (score >= beta):
            return score

        if (score > bestscore):
            bestscore = score

        if (score > alpha):
            alpha = score

    if legal == 0:
        if incheck:
            return -INF + ply
        else:
            return 0

    return bestscore


def quiesce(board, alpha, beta):
    if is_time_limit_reached():
        return 0

    if board.is_insufficient_material():
        return 0

    stand_pat = evaluate_board(board)
    if (stand_pat >= beta):
        return beta
    if (alpha < stand_pat):
        alpha = stand_pat

    for move in board.legal_moves:
        if board.is_capture(move):
            board.push(move)

            score = -quiesce(board, -beta, -alpha)
            board.pop()

            if (score >= beta):
                return beta

            if (score > alpha):
                alpha = score

    return alpha


def selectmove(board, depth):
    global ply 

    bestMove = chess.Move.null()
    bestValue = -INF
    alpha = -INF
    beta = INF

    for move in board.legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        ply += 1

        boardValue = -alphabeta(board, -beta, -alpha, depth - 1)
        if boardValue > bestValue:
            bestValue = boardValue
            bestMove = move

        if (boardValue > alpha):
            alpha = boardValue

        board.pop()
        ply -= 1

        if is_time_limit_reached():
            break

    return bestMove, bestValue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global timems
    global start_time
    global ply

    fen = chess.STARTING_FEN
    # fen = "1k6/7Q/1K6/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"  # mate in 1
    # fen = "kbK5/pp6/1P6/8/8/8/8/R7 w - - 0 1"  # mate in 2
    # fen = "rnbqkb1r/1p2pppp/p2p1n2/8/3NP3/2N5/PPP2PPP/R1BQKB1R w KQkq - 0 6"  # sicilian
    
    depth = MAX_DEPTH
    timems = MAX_TIME_MS

    board = chess.Board(fen)

    while True:
        userinput = input('> ')
        line = userinput.rstrip()

        if line == 'go':
            bestmove, bestscore = None, None
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            ply = 0

            if not board.is_game_over():
                for d in range(1, depth+1):
                    move, score = selectmove(board, d)

                    elapse = 1000 * (time.perf_counter() - start_time)

                    if elapse >= timems:
                        break  # Don't overwrite our bestmove from the time-interrupted search.

                    bestmove = move
                    bestscore = score

                    if abs(bestscore) > MATE_SCORE:
                        mate = value_to_mate(bestscore)
                        print(f'info depth {d} score mate {mate} time {int(elapse)} pv {bestmove}')  # time is in millisec
                    else:
                        print(f'info depth {d} score {bestscore} time {int(elapse)} pv {bestmove}')  # time is in millisec

                board.push(bestmove)  # update board with the bestmove
                print(f'info time {int(1000*(time.perf_counter() - start_time))}')
                print(f'bestmove {bestmove}')
            else:
                print('Game is over!')

        elif line == 'new':
            board = chess.Board()
            depth = MAX_DEPTH
            timems = MAX_TIME_MS
            print(board)
            print(f'max depth: {depth}, max time ms: {timems}')

        elif 'position fen ' in line:
            fen = ' '.join(line.split()[2:7])
            board = chess.Board(fen)

        elif line == 'board':
            print(board)

        elif line == 'fen':
            print(board.fen())

        elif line == 'epd':
            print(board.epd())

        elif 'time' in line:
            timems = int(line.split()[1])

        elif 'depth' in line:
            depth = int(line.split()[1])

        elif line == 'game':
            game = chess.pgn.Game()
            print(game.from_board(board))

        elif line == 'quit':
            break

        else:
            # assume user has entered a move
            try:
                board.push(chess.Move.from_uci(line))
            except ValueError:
                print(f'illegal move {line}')
```

#### Output

##### Playing a game

```
> new
r n b q k b n r
p p p p p p p p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
P P P P P P P P
R N B Q K B N R
max depth: 16, max time ms: 120000
> time 5000
> e2e4
> go
info depth 1 score 10 time 18 pv g8f6
info depth 2 score -40 time 140 pv g8f6
info depth 3 score 10 time 973 pv g8f6
info time 5001
bestmove g8f6
> board
r n b q k b . r
p p p p p p p p
. . . . . n . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . P . . .
. . . . . . . .
P P P P . P P P
R N B Q K B N R
> b1c3
> go
info depth 1 score 10 time 19 pv b8c6
info depth 2 score -20 time 421 pv d7d5
info depth 3 score 10 time 2865 pv d7d5
info time 5000
bestmove d7d5
> board
r n b q k b . r
p p p . p p p p
. . . . . n . .
. . . p . . . .
. . . . P . . .
. . N . . . . .
P P P P . P P P
R . B Q K B N R
> game
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]

1. e4 Nf6 2. Nc3 d5 *
> quit
```

##### Setup position

```
> position fen kbK5/pp6/1P6/8/8/8/8/R7 w - - 0 1
> board
k b K . . . . .
p p . . . . . .
. P . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
R . . . . . . .
> time 5000
> go
info depth 1 score 10 time 10 pv a1a5
info depth 2 score 10 time 92 pv a1a5
info depth 3 score mate 2 time 362 pv a1a6
info depth 4 score mate 2 time 2151 pv a1a6
info time 5001
bestmove a1a6
> board
k b K . . . . .
p p . . . . . .
R P . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
> go
info depth 1 score 480 time 5 pv b7a6
info depth 2 score mate -1 time 32 pv b8c7
info depth 3 score mate -1 time 184 pv b8c7
info depth 4 score mate -1 time 1314 pv b8c7
info time 5000
bestmove b8c7
> go
info depth 1 score mate 1 time 4 pv a6a7
info depth 2 score mate 1 time 37 pv a6a7
info depth 3 score mate 1 time 143 pv a6a7
info depth 4 score mate 1 time 878 pv a6a7
info depth 5 score mate 1 time 4305 pv a6a7
info time 5001
bestmove a6a7
> go
Game is over!
>
```

Comment: Thanks for example code. Since posting this ive improved the code to something similar to what you posted here. After testing it with the positions on the chess programming wiki it got 6 out of 24 correct.  It works somewhat decently now, it just needs further improvement with move ordering and the evaluation. Possibly tablebases, if i can implement them.